# Delay in Serial Communication when talking between Arduino and Python

Tags: arduino, serial-port, delay

I have an Arduino-controlled robot with a gyroscope, and I'm trying to send data from it over to a Python program run on a Raspberry Pi. However, there's a 1-2 second delay between me moving the robot, and info being printed out the python program. I've tried restarting my computer, as well as replugging the wires. Is there anything I'm doing in my code that is causing this or is it a hardware thing?

The robot is connected to a Raspberry Pi, with which I have a headless setup. The python program is being run on the Pi but can be viewed on my desktop over SSH. The program has no delay when I connect the robot to my desktop and run the python program on it as well.

Arduino Program:

```cpp
#include <robot's file>

Gyro gyro; //Object using an imported class

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial) {}
}

void loop() {
  gyro.read(); //Reads the robot's yaw and puts it into variable "z"
  Serial.println(gyro.z);
}
```

Python Program:

```py
import serial
from serial.serialutil import SerialException

ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0", 115200)

try:
  ser.open()
except SerialException:
    print("Port already opened")

while True: print(ser.readline())
```

Comment: Why not call [Serial.flush()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/flush/) after arduino's [Serial.println()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/println/)? Please read the Notes and Warnings on [Serial.write()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/write/).

Answer (score 0):

looks to me that everything is good in your code.
Most of the delay is related to your PC computing time.
If you want to speed up the process I would suggest to interface an Oled display (or an LCD) to display directly your data: using your PC is good for the initial testing, but if you need immediate response it is better to manage the data interfacing directly.
This link may support you: https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/1.3inch_OLED_HAT All the best

Answer (score 0):

After some testing, I think I've figured it out.

Printing to terminal takes a long time, which made the Arduino program faster than the Python program, creating a buildup of data, causing the delay. I've fixed the problem by only printing out data every 10 iterations. The problem would also be fixed if I stored the data into a variable, and did not call the print() function.